# Disable selection on webpage BUT not on forms or people can't select input fields by mouse

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

What i'm trying to do is to make the whole page unselectable and i've done it with this:

```
$('*').disableSelection();
```

however when you are filling out a form you can't select it by clicking, for that i've changed my code to:

```
$('*:not(input)').disableSelection();
```

but this didn't work also... i tried to call an enableSelection() for $('input') but that also couldn't override disableSelection... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed it to use :input (as that includes all types of input), but input also worked:
http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/kWB6g/

Comment: just a little note here: having it wrapped around $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); also helps (didn't work without it at first in an external js file)

Comment: @Logan, jsFiddle wraps the code per default (onLoad) as you can see in the left hand menu. That's why it worked there but not in your file ;)

Comment: @Richard D: Your fiddle doesn't work on Firefox, I can't select the text in the input box.

Comment: @Darth Oh yeah, I hadn't tested in firefox. Worked in chrome.

Comment: @Richard D, it's because `.disableSelection` doesn't have any effect on inputs at all in Webkit. Remove `:not(:input)` and it still works in Webkit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really bad idea and something that will be both difficult and CPU-intensive to perform.

`.disableSelection()` will disable selection of the current element and all of its children, so even if you disregard certain elements in the selector those will not be selectable if their parent have gotten its selection disabled.

Why disabling selection of a whole document is not just a bad idea but a bad practice is because it hampers usability. That is something that should be reserved to some very specific cases, such as improving security or implementing spam-protection like captchas; then you might have to cut down on usability.

The `.disableSelection`-method was created for the purpose to omit irrelevant content from being selected, such as specific ui elements like tabs, buttons or other descriptive ui elements. So its really a matter of improving usability, not hamper it.

In the end, this is far from a guaranteed way to stop users from selecting your content and will only make them irritated and less prone to return.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed response. I really appreciate it, I'm using it on a web application (a game to be more specific) on the draggable areas- therefore I think it is worth it in my case.

Comment: @Logan, then why use the asterisk selector on the whole document? It shouldn't be used like that, and really doesn't make any sense in your case. Just disable selection on those draggable areas by using a class 'disable-selection'. $('.disable-selection').disableSelection(); Will be so much faster!